# Time efficient algorithm for Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I need an algorithm which can solve the problem below efficiently:

> Given a tree (not binary) with maximum of 200000 edges and 3 nodes x,y,z. Write an algorithm which returns true if either y lies in the path of x and z or z lies in the path of x and y. The number of queries is in the order of 10^5.

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a "do my homework for me" site. What have you tried? How did that fail?

Comment: @svick actually this problem narrows down to a problem ie finding lowest common ancestor of two nodes in a undirected graph or tree (not a binary tree). Need help in this regard. Sorry I posted my problem in stack overflow. I did becoz of some time constraint ...Can u plz suggest me some algorithm?

Comment: @svick: You can just VTC these things.

Comment: do you still need the answer to this problem? You can use many ways to solve the lowest common ancestor problem - DFS traversal order + Range Minimum Query, 2^K parent decomposition (I think), Heavy Light Decomposition .. etc which can all answer queries in O(log N) with O(N) or O(N log N) pre-computation

Answer (score -1):

Seems straightforward. Since it's a tree, to test for `x -> y -> z`, start at `z` then traverse up to the root of the tree. Similarly, to test for `x -> z -> y`, start at `y`, then traverse up to the root of the tree. You could of course start at `z` and `y` at the same time, and traverse up the tree towards the root until you find that either of the two path conditions are met, or you find a contradictory information such as 'z' and 'y' belonging to two different branches of 'x', or not finding `x` even when you traversed all the way up to the root.

The worst case for this simple algorithm would occur when you have a completely linear tree with each node having just one child, such that `x` is the root, `y` is `100000` edges away from `x` (i.e. half way), and `z` is the leaf. I am not sure where the limit `10^5` comes from.